# text-overflow doesn't work in flex box as a child element

Tags: html, css

I can't apply text-overflow to `<p>` which inside flex-box.
whole texts are been overflowed hidden when window width smaller.

how can I deal with this?

```
  <header class="flex_box">
    <p class="long_text">some very long text. this is very long text </p>
   
  </header> 

 /** css  */

 .flex_box {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center; 
  }
 .long_text {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the width.

```
 .long_text {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
  }
```